# MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings gamedig problem

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, gamedig

Hello i have a problem  and its
**its   if (typeof data !== 'string') throw new error(errorMessage);                                          RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings.**

i trying on players to put the amount of players that the minecraft server has like:

**Players Online: 79 Players**

my code its:

```
let state = null;

let jugadores = 0;

setInterval(() => {


  Gamedig.query({
    type: 'minecraft',
    host: 'mc.latinplay.net',
    port: '25565'
  })
  .then((updatedState) => {
    state = updatedState;
    players = state.players.length;
  });
}, 6000);

module.exports = new Command({
  name: cmdconfig.EstadoCommand,
  description: cmdconfig.EstadoCommandDesc,


  async run(interaction) {

      const LatinStatus = new Discord.MessageEmbed() 
    .setColor('RANDOM') 
       .addField('**Players:**', 'players')
      .addField('**Status**', "**Online**", true);
      interaction.reply({
        embeds: [LatinEstado],
      });
  
    }
  },
);
```

Comment: How do you send the `embed`?

Comment: interaction.reply({
        embeds: [LatinStatus],
      });

Comment: i update the code.

Comment: these two: `let state = null;` and `let jugadores = 0;` what is these for? Did you also called it on your embed somewhere?

Comment: thats is the api of gamedig, its for calling from the "mc.latinplay.net" the players that are on the game, and no, i dont called my embed from any other place

Comment: Found the problem, `.addField('**Players:**', 'players')` the `'player'` causing the problem, you need to define your `player` like `${players}` but i think it still wont work since your `player` is inside of `.then` function.

Comment: Alright thanks you, is there a way to make it possible to work?

Comment: ill try like this   .addField('**Players:**', '${Players}', true), but it doesnt work either, im using gamedig, i want to catch how many persons are on the server

Comment: Its `case sensitive`. And you are using `quote` and it must be `back quote` "**`**",

Comment: \`${players}\` must be like these

Comment: it works thanks you so much but its says Players: 0, i think that is bc of** let players = 0;** i'm trying getting how many players are on the server, but it doesnt show up

Comment: If you have `let players = 0` You just need to remove it

Comment: ```   .addField('**Jugadores:**', `${players}`, true)
                                     ^

ReferenceError: players is not defined``` having that issue.

Comment: Can you exactly edit your post with your current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code from your recent:

```
let state = null;

let jugadores = 0;

setInterval(() => {


  Gamedig.query({
    type: 'minecraft',
    host: 'mc.latinplay.net',
    port: '25565'
  })
  .then((updatedState) => {
    state = updatedState;
    players = state.players.length || "0"; //adding || operator so no error will occure
  });
}, 6000);

module.exports = new Command({
  name: cmdconfig.EstadoCommand,
  description: cmdconfig.EstadoCommandDesc,


  async run(interaction) {

      const LatinStatus = new Discord.MessageEmbed() 
    .setColor('RANDOM') 
       .addField('**Players:**', 'players')
      .addField('**Status**', "**Online**", true);
      interaction.reply({
        embeds: [LatinEstado],
      });
  
    }
  },
);
```

Ive seen alot of errors in here, you can also use an operator called `or` in operator `||` to prevent error when `players` reached on `0` members.

```
module.exports = new Command({
  name: cmdconfig.EstadoCommand,
  description: cmdconfig.EstadoCommandDesc,


async run(interaction) {
let state = null;

let jugadores = 0; //I also don't understand what is these for.

setInterval(() => {
  Gamedig.query({
    type: 'minecraft',
    host: 'mc.latinplay.net',
    port: '25565'
  })
  .then((updatedState) => {
     state = updatedState;
     players = state.players.length;
     const LatinStatus = new Discord.MessageEmbed() 
    .setColor('RANDOM') 
    .addField('**Players:**', `${players}`) //also it must be `${players}`
    .addField('**Status**', "**Online**", true);
    interaction.reply({
      embeds: [LatinEstado],
    });
  });
}, 6000);
    }
  },
);
```

EDIT:

I tried your code and caught an error such as `Error: Failed all 1 attempts`

so you can use `.catch` function

```
setInterval(() => {
  Gamedig.query({
    type: 'minecraft',
    host: 'mc.latinplay.net',
    port: '25565'
  }).catch((err) => {
     console.log() //or
     console.log(err)
  })
  .then((updatedState) => {
     state = updatedState;
     players = state.players.length;
     const LatinStatus = new Discord.MessageEmbed() 
    .setColor('RANDOM') 
    .addField('**Players:**', `${players || "0"}`) //also it must be `${players}`
    .addField('**Status**', "**Online**", true);
    interaction.reply({
      embeds: [LatinEstado],
    });
  });
}, 6000);
```